# How to remove space at the bottom of list in navbar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar in asp.net mvc web application and when I hover on it I Want background to occupy all space but at some of the list Items it does not occupy spaces at the bottom as You can see in the image
[image: navbar image]

li elements of *services*, *signup* and *login* occupying all spaces at the bottom but *Home* and *aboutUs* are not. i tried *margin:0;* at li element but nothing happens.

```css
.navbar {
    font-size: 1.25em !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0.5px black;
    border : none;
}


.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #00ff99 !important;    
}


.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #00804d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: #000099 !important;
    font-family: 'Brush Script MT' !important;
    font-size: 1.50em !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black !important;
}

.navbar-nav li{
    margin:0;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: black;    
}

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .Dropdown-btn:hover, .Dropdown-btn:focus {
        /*background-color: #8080ff;*/
        background-color: rgba(128, 128, 255,0.5) !important;
        color: white important;
    }


.glyph-pad {
    left: -4px;
    top: 4px;}


.Dropdown-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 13px 13px;
    margin: 0;
}


.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00ff99;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

    .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        float: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }


ul.dropdown-menu > li > a {    
    color: black !important;
}

    ul.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(128, 128, 255,0.5) !important;
        color: white !important;
    }

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    /*background-color: #8080ff;*/
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 153,0.8);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              <a href="#">E-HealthCare</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Home</a>                        
                      </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="Dropdown-btn btn-block text-left dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Services
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>   
                        </div>
                    </li>

                  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("SignUp","Account")"><Span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></Span> Sign Up </a>
                        
                    </li><li>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Login","Account")"><Span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></Span> Login </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[This is working codepen link](https://codepen.io/sal121/pen/zYWMZYo)

Comment: Above code snippet not working properly.

Comment: i have used some of mvc's helper methods that's why its not showing proper output and therefore i added image for the output

Comment: i've added codepen link you can check it out

Comment: The root cause of your problem is the use of classes `.navbar-left` and `.navbar-right`. This makes the `ul's` float left and right respectively and taking them out of the document flow. Since the height of the right menu is larger than the one on the left, you get the space you are referring to. You could consider setting the height of the navbar container to a fixed height in pixels and set the height of the `ul's` to 100%, or explore the flexbox options of Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @gerard thanks for your suggestion i gave height to navbar and it worked. also post the comment as answer so that i can accept as answer